# CSS styling works in Mozilla, but not in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, cross-browser, stylesheet

I have a problem, because I've made a custom stylesheet for my website and it doesn't work in Chrome. The links are blue, visited pages are magenta and the links underline on hover. The code which doesn't work:

```
a:link,
a:visited {
    color:black;

}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:active,
a.active {
    text-decoration:none;

}

a:hover,
a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color:#575757;
}
```

I've tried to figure out whats happening and it seems that Chrome doesn't see these properties. It overrides them with:

```
a:-webkit-any-link {
color: -webkit-link;
text-decoration: underline;
cursor: auto;
}
```

My stylesheet works fine with Mozilla so I think that the issue is with Chrome and not my stylesheet. What should I do to display the website properly in Chrome?

Comment: It works fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/SLaks/jNLVZ/  What do you see in the console?

Comment: Is `a:-webkit-any-link` in your stylesheet?

Comment: @putvande No. It seems to be added by the browser when loading the page.

Comment: `-webkit-any-link` is not a valid pseudo class AFAIK

Comment: @SLaks I see the text in console the way it should look like.

Comment: @Paulie_D: It's WebKit's implementation of the new `:any-link` pseudo-class: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14436526/whats-the-any-link-pseudo-class-for/14437502#14437502

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There was a miracle and the website now works properly even in Chrome. I don't know why, because I haven't changed anything, but I suspect that Chrome was loading CSS from the stored CACHE and that was the reason why it displayed the website wrong.